# FineUploader to Azure Storage

Tags: azure, fine-uploader

When uploading to Azure Storage, does FineUploader send the file directly to Azure Storage or to the server first?

I noticed on the website that with S3, one can upload directly but the fact that S3 was singled out got me curious.

[image]

I'm looking for a really robust solution to upload files - even large files up to 10 GB - to Azure Storage. Wanted to see if FineUploader could be the answer for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When uploading to Azure Storage, does FineUploader send the file directly to Azure Storage or to the server first?

Fine Uploader Azure sends the files directly to Azure Cloud Storage. You *do* need a server to generate Shared Access Signatures for each request. Fine Uploader Azure will contact your SAS server before each upload request (or before any request to Azure) to obtain a SAS. More information on the Azure feature page at http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/azure.html.

Fine Uploader S3 functions using a similar workflow, but there is also an option to upload files directly to S3 without maintaining your own signature server. That particular option is not available with Fine Uploader Azure.

Comment: Ray...I have a question. You mentioned that Fine Uploader uploads directly to Azure Storage. I went through the documentation and couldn't find anything regarding CORS configuration. AFAIK, for direct blob upload from browser to storage to  work, proper CORS configuration is required. Am I missing something here? Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/azure.html